# Lottie animation in collection view swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, lottie

I’m trying to use lottie animation into my collection view
I tried to add animation view to the story board but I must to use one name of animation and I want to show different animation for each cell
Thanks !

```
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    
        if let cell = cell as? WorkOutCollectionViewCell{
              cell.animationView! = .init(name: workout[indexPath.row])
              cell.animationView!.frame = view.bounds
              cell.animationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
              cell.animationView!.loopMode = .loop
              cell.animationView!.animationSpeed = 0.5

                //view.addSubview(cell.animationView)
            
              cell.animationView!.play()
            
        }
    
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
cell.animationView! = .init(name: workout[indexPath.row])
```

to

```
cell.animationView.animation = Animation.named(workout[indexPath.row])
```